# Laravel / Mysql groupby ordering

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the command

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM episodes ORDER BY created_at DESC) and t1 
 GROUP BY serial_id 
 ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

which I will return series where the last episode added by `created_at`. But the problem is that when I had it on hosting everything worked but now I put it on the VPS server and there I'm always lists the first episode. If i add `desc` after `group by serial_id` it's work but it is not possible on laravel (`-> groupBy ('serial_id')`)

Shared hosting:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+
| id      | serial_id   | part   |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|    8124 | 12          | s02e10 |
|     362 | 8           | s09e12 |
|    4673 | 9           | s01e12 |
|     871 | 4           | s03e24 |
+---------+-------------+--------+
```

My VPS:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+
| id      | serial_id   | part   |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|    8124 | 12          | s01e01 |
|     362 | 8           | s01e01 |
|    4673 | 9           | s01e01 |
|     871 | 4           | s01e01 |
+---------+-------------+--------+
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Probably you will have to use RAW in this case: `groupBy(DB::raw('serial_id desc'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will have to use RAW in this case: `groupBy(DB::raw('serial_id desc'))`

like below

```
DB::table( DB::raw("(SELECT * FROM episodes ORDER BY created_at DESC) and t1") )->groupBy(DB::raw('serial_id desc'))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a lot of errors in your query.

missing a tablename between `FROM` and `ORDER BY`

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM 
--                         ^^ where is the tablename ?

ORDER BY episodes created_at DESC) and t1 GROUP BY ORDER BY serial_id created_at DESC
--               ^^ missing comma,  ^^ this 'and' seems in the wrong place and you havent't column for group by and in last another missing comma
```

try something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * 
            FROM  my_table  ORDER BY episodes,  created_at DESC)  t1 
GROUP BY my_column_for_group_by  
ORDER BY serial_id, created_at DESC
```

In laravel you could assign the order direction using:

```
 ->orderBy('serial_id')
 ->orderBy('created_at',  'DESC')
```

Comment: Sorry command was bad, this is correct `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM episodes ORDER BY created_at DESC) and t1 GROUP BY serial_id ORDER BY created_at DESC`

Comment: @domiQ I have update the asnwer for composite order by and direction in laravel

Comment: can not be wrong setting? the shared hosting works but not the VPS?

Comment: no no, my script working on shared hosting gives all recently added episodes but VPS gives all first episodes.... I added demonstrations tables

Comment: @domiQ  are you sure your problem is not related to the VPS cache ..?